# Matrix must be positive definite (Math.Net C# library)

Tags: c#, statistics, mathnet-numerics

I'm encountering a strange issue with the Math.Net Numerics library for C#. My code worked perfectly fine until recently (nothing has changed as far as I can tell) but I'm now getting the error message from the title at the line where it tries to calculate the multiple regression.

Each list has 493 double values so does anyone know what I can do to fix these issues?

```
Vector<double> vectorArrayBuy = CreateVector.Dense(listMRInfoBuy.ElementAt(0).OutputBuy.ToArray());

var matrixArrayBuy = CreateMatrix.DenseOfColumnArrays(listMRInfoBuy.ElementAt(0).ListValuesBuy.ToArray(), listMRInfoBuy.ElementAt(1).ListValuesBuy.ToArray(), listMRInfoBuy.ElementAt(2).ListValuesBuy.ToArray(),
                                listMRInfoBuy.ElementAt(3).ListValuesBuy.ToArray(), listMRInfoBuy.ElementAt(4).ListValuesBuy.ToArray(), listMRInfoBuy.ElementAt(5).ListValuesBuy.ToArray(), listMRInfoBuy.ElementAt(6).ListValuesBuy.ToArray(),
                                listMRInfoBuy.ElementAt(7).ListValuesBuy.ToArray(), listMRInfoBuy.ElementAt(8).ListValuesBuy.ToArray(), listMRInfoBuy.ElementAt(9).ListValuesBuy.ToArray(), listMRInfoBuy.ElementAt(10).ListValuesBuy.ToArray(),
                                listMRInfoBuy.ElementAt(11).ListValuesBuy.ToArray());

var itemsBuy = MultipleRegression.NormalEquations(matrixArrayBuy, vectorArrayBuy);
```

Comment: NormalEquations uses Cholesky decomposition https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition for which matrix should be hernitian and positive definite https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix. As error message says - your matrix is not.

Comment: @Evk Sorry for sounding like an idiot but how do I make sure my matrix is positive definite with math.net numerics and how do I fix it so that it is positive definite?

Comment: Your system might be ill-conditioned. What does `matrixArrayBuy.ConditionNumber()` return? Does it by chance work if instead of `MultipleRegression.NormalEquations` you use `MultipleRegression.QR` or `MultipleRegression.Svd`?

Comment: (maybe NormalEquations should fall back to another decomposition if the matrix is not positive definite)

Comment: Unfortunately my knowledge of this stuff is quite rusty, but I think you can use QR method which uses QR decomposition which does not have such requirements to matrix but is generally slower. Same applies to SVD. But first recheck if your inputs are correct.

Comment: @ChristophRüegg I will try those in just a second and let you know what it returns. In the meantime, I had a related question about the matrix object in math.net numerics. How do I create a matrix programatically like Matrix test = new Matrix();
test.Add(new List<double>() list1);
test.Add(new List<double>() list2);

Comment: Make sure your parameters are not null (matrixArrayBuy and vactorArrayBuy).  If this is not the case you may have a negative index into an array.  I had similar error message in MatLab.  We were using a find method to get the peak value into a two dimensional array (x,y).  The peak value Y returned a negative x value.  Then we use the x value into an index of an array.  The code failed when x was negative but worked when x was positive.

Comment: @ChristophRüegg matrixArrayBuy.ConditionNumber() returned with this error: Algorithm failed to converge

Comment: @Evk Correct me if I'm wrong but the inputs are correct if they are all positive values right?

Comment: @jdweng I just have to check that all inputs use positive numbers?

Comment: Did you try with old data?  The new data failed to converge.  Like I said earlier make sure matrixArrayBuy and vectorArrayBuy where not null.

Comment: @jdweng It turns out that I had some infinity and NaN values and that caused the exception. I created an answer showing how I fixed this issue in my own code so that it might help someone else in the future

Comment: Returning positive and negative infinity for matrix operations is not unusual.  The code that does the processing has to allow for these results and get best answer(s) by ignoring these values.

Comment: @jdweng That's not it. Some elements of the matrix are inf or nan. You can't just ignore these in a cholesky decomposition

Comment: How do we know what type of matrix we have.   You are assuming its cholesky.  These NAN just may be nulls of the equations.  Dividing by zero will produce NAN.

Comment: @jdweng I'm not assuming anything. NormalEquations uses Cholesky decomposition (https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearRegression/MultipleRegression.htm#NormalEquations``1). Cholesky decomposition isn't a "type of matrix". It's an algorithm that factors a Hermitian positive definite matrix into the product of a lower triangular matrix and its conjugate transpose. I understand what a NaN is. Dividing by zero results in INF rather than NaN.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by switching on the fly for the different equations to see which one returned the correct answers and didn't throw this exception. Here is my solution to this problem which I hope helps someone else out.

```
public Vector<double> CalculateWithQR(Matrix<double> x, Vector<double> y)
    {
        Vector<double> result = null;

        try
        {
            result = MultipleRegression.QR(x, y);

            // check for NaN and infinity
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
            {
                var value = result.ElementAt(i);

                if (Double.IsNaN(value) || Double.IsInfinity(value))
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        return result;
    }

    public Vector<double> CalculateWithNormal(Matrix<double> x, Vector<double> y)
    {
        Vector<double> result = null;

        try
        {
            result = MultipleRegression.NormalEquations(x, y);

            // check for NaN and infinity
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
            {
                var value = result.ElementAt(i);

                if (Double.IsNaN(value) || Double.IsInfinity(value))
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        return result;
    }

    public Vector<double> CalculateWithSVD(Matrix<double> x, Vector<double> y)
    {
        Vector<double> result = null;

        try
        {
            result = MultipleRegression.Svd(x, y);

            // check for NaN and infinity
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
            {
                var value = result.ElementAt(i);

                if (Double.IsNaN(value) || Double.IsInfinity(value))
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        return result;
    }

    public Vector<double> FindBestMRSolution(Matrix<double> x, Vector<double> y)
    {
        Vector<double> result = null;

        try
        {
            result = CalculateWithNormal(x, y);

            if (result != null)
            {
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                result = CalculateWithSVD(x, y);

                if (result != null)
                {
                    return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = CalculateWithQR(x, y);

                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't make a whole lot of sense. You said that the issue was an exception raised by `NormalEquations`. If so, why are you checking the return values. You don't get anything back if it raises an exception. I suspect that you haven't got to the bottom of the problem yet, and this trial and error programming is not going to yield benefits long term.

Answer (score 0):

"Matrix not positive definite" probably means that you have fewer than n independent equations, which in turn means you don't have n independent data, which probably means your data are defective in some way (e.g. they were read in incorrect and they're actually all the same or something like that).

Perhaps you can edit your question to show what are the data you are working with. Maybe you have fewer than n data to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a solution for those (like me) who do not remember linear algebra or advanced stats from your school days.

1. If you haven't already, apply the "Analysis ToolPak" Add-In in Excel
2. Paste your independent and dependent variables into a worksheet
3. Go to Data -> Data Analysis -> Regression
4. Provide the ranges it asks for and run the regression
5. In the regression results you'll find that one or more p-values or t-stats return an a div/0 or NUM error.
6. Remove those independent variables from your call to the MathNet regression and run again.

This should fix it.

I then went on to add an iterative try and catch that would remove the independent variables, based upon the specific circumstance, and run it again.

IHTH